# Macro with Microsoft Access Object Library - Workaround to use it without Access installed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, xslt

I think the answer is no, but I will try it anyways just in case ...

I wrote a VBA macro to be used in Excel that uses the Microsoft Access Object Library.
Is there a workaround to be able to use this Excel macro on a computer without Access installed ?

The function I am interested in is `Application.TransformXML` (or `Access.Application.TransformXML` in my case), to transform a XML file in another one with a different format using a XSLT file.
The computer I wish to use it on has very minimal tools installed and it is not easy to add new ones (otherwise I would just install Access, or even better a proper XSLT processor, and be done with it).

Thanks

Comment: I can't think of how needing and using a Access feature without Access is possible. However, since you are using Excel, it has some REALLY amazing xml features, and in fact more then access. So, maybe dig around in Excel - it might have some alterative road and means to achieve this goal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into more details into the Xml features offered by excel!

Comment: Access Runtime is free. Maybe that would allow the Access code to function.

Comment: Thank you June7, the question you linked to confirms I can do it with only VBA excel functions. Now I just need to work on it to implement it. Solved ! :)